# AngularJS using $apply without $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started working with AngularJS and I embraced the convention for writing controllers with this, not with $scope. So my controllers look like this:

```
myApp.controller("SomeController", function(){
    this.myModel={id:-1, name:"empty"};
});

<div ng-controller="SomeController as ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.myModel.name" />
</div>
```

Now, I changed the myModel object in the controller in a way like this:

```
this.myModel=someOtherObjectFromAForeignSource;
```

... and the value inside the input control doesn't change. I read about the $apply function and it's use but since i use the "this" convention, I don't have a $scope variable.

How do I call the $apply method?

Comment: Why do you think you need `$apply()`? Where does that other data come from? - Your `input` is also set to the `name` property - does your new object contain that property?

Comment: Yes, it contains the name property - this new object is coming from a 3rd party control, and angular can't register the change automatically. Anyway, my question is still how to use the $apply method without the use of $scope?

Comment: I think, you can't use $apply without $scope or $rootScope.

Comment: Can you post the code where you do `this.myModel=someOtherObjectFromAForeignSource;`. Because the model should be updated IF you are not using a third party library in your controller (like jQuery).

Comment: There is apply() method in javascript. consider using that..

Comment: i really dont think, you would need $apply, there is some other problem

Comment: doesn't really matter anyway, my question is how to call the $apply method without injecting $scope?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can certainly still use $scope with the `controller as` syntax with no issue.

In fact that is how you would handle events (`$on`, `$broadcast`, `$emit`) just inject it into your controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
   //set your properties/methods as you are
   this.message = 'foo';
   this.yell = function(){
     this.message = this.message.toUpperCase() + '!!!';
   };

  var vm = this;
  //and use $apply as needed
  somethingOutsideOfAngular(function(value){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      vm.message = value;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So I still need to inject $scope if I want to use $apply? I tried it like this and it certainly works but I thought there was another way.

Comment: Meteo, that is correct, because `$apply` is a method on the `$scope` object.

Comment: It isn't exactly the answer I wanted but OK - do you perhaps know where could I confirm that you really NEED to inject $scope for $apply?

Comment: The documentation for `$apply` which states that it is a method upon the Scope object is here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply And since based upon your need to call `$apply` the only way to get to it is the actual `Scope` object by injecting `$scope`

Comment: This is certainly a limitatiom of using `controllerAs` syntax, because you will have to inject and invoke `$scope` anyway as shown in the answer

Comment: You can use `$timeout` or `$evalasync` to achieve kind of the same thing - but then, you have dependencies on them which I don't think give you much...