# $on('$stateChangeStart') WITHOUT $scope or $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

EDIT: have moved to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479080/ui-router-scope-and-controlleras?noredirect=1#comment68202490_40479080) for clarity

Comment: you can not use `$on` without `$scope` or `$rootScope`

Comment: See this answer and comments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27568151/angularjs-using-apply-without-scope/27568410#27568410

Answer (score 3):

`$on` is a `$scope` function so you can't use it with `this`. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on).

If you want to use `$on`, you can use `$scope` along with the `controller as` syntax.

Comment: I injected $scope, and now I get `Unknown provider: ` error, but it does not say the provider, just a space.

Comment: @holtc can you share a fiddle so that I may have a look at the code please.

Comment: Unknown provider usually results from angular not being able to resolve dependencies. Can you share a more detailed version of your code/ plunker?

Comment: moved to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479080/ui-router-scope-and-controlleras?noredirect=1#comment68202490_40479080

Comment: I think you've already received the answer to your error. btw you should keep the question the way it was before for reference :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try $injector

```
$injector.get('$rootScope').$on('$stateChangeStart',
  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      // write your logic here
  });
```

or

```
angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope').$on('$stateChangeStart',
  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
      // write your logic here
  });
```