# ui.router, $scope, and controllerAs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am unable to get the following to work, I keep getting an `Unknown provider` error.  Any ideas?

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url : "/",
            templateUrl : "resources/static/views/home.html",
            controller: "HomeCtrl",
            controllerAs: "homeCtrl"
        }
    );
});

app.controller("HomeCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    var _this = this;

    // do stuff

}]);
```

Full Error:

```
angular.1.5.8.min.js:118 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=<div ui-view="" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20HomeCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:6:412
    at http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:43:174
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:40:432)
    at http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:43:236
    at d (http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:40:432)
    at e (http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:41:158)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:42:24)
    at http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular.1.5.8.min.js:90:32
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/resources/scripts/js/include/angular-ui-router.0.3.1.min.js:7:23872)
```

And [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=)

And html

```
<div>Home</div>
```

For clarity, I need to use controllerAs, so removing it is not an option.

EDIT: Must be a bug in version 0.3.1 of ui.router, when I switched to 0.3.2 it worked fine.

Comment: post the complete error and html

Comment: added in the edit

Comment: HTML code of yours

Comment: html shouldn't matter at all but added

Comment: you haven't closed the `app.config` correctly. it shld end with `})`, pls change that

Comment: typo when posting the question

Comment: are you using a service anywhere in your application and injected `$scope` as a dependency into it?

Comment: don't use `$scope` when using `controllerAs`. just use `this` inside your controller ...

Comment: need access to the $scope functions, anyways issue resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `data-ui-view` in index.html,

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
  <h2>AngularJS Ui router - Demonstration</h2>
  <div data-ui-view=""></div>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router']);
myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.when("", "/home");
  $stateProvider
    .state("home", {
      url: "/home",
      templateUrl: "home.html",
      controller: 'HomeCtrl',
      controllerAs: "home"
    });
});
myApp.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
     vm.hello = "DEMO";

}]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/EWDVf0RDfzvo8oPH9kdM?p=info)**

Comment: The problem is not in my html, it is in the js

Comment: @holtc ok glad you got it fixed

Comment: it is not fixed yet

Comment: @holtc Please check the demo

Comment: your demo does not use controllerAs, and does not work when that is added

Comment: there is not much difference, check the updated plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/EWDVf0RDfzvo8oPH9kdM?p=preview

Comment: that's weird it isn't working in my app, I have no idea why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127587/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-holtc).

Comment: figured it out, must be a bug in version 0.3.1 of ui.router, when I switched to 0.3.2 it worked, thanks for the help!